# Como trazer um resultado de uma pagina .php para outra pagina .php usando javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

O código abaixo esta funcionando muito bem, porem ele mostra o resultado na pagina dele submit.php.

```
    <?php

    // submit.php


    echo $CODNOME;

    if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
      $msg = "mensagem1";
    } 

    else if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
      $msg = "mensagem2";
    }

    else {
      $msg = "opção fixa";
    }


    echo $msg;

   ?>
```

o que eu gostaria e que ele executasse a função no submit.php e depois voltasse com o resultado para imprimir.php em na div 
**print**

```
<!-- imprimir.php !-->

<form method="post" id="CODNOME" action="submit.php">
      <nav class="zz z_meio2 borda ">
  insira o codigo
<br>
      <input type="text" name="CODNOME" id="CODNOME"><br>
      <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>

      </nav>
    </form>

<div class="print" STYLE="width:660px;">
  <?php echo $msg;?>
     <p>*conteúdo html e php</p> 
</div>
```

então como criar um javascripit para pegar o dado inserido pelo usuário na imprimir.php enviar para  submit.php e trazer com o resultado na div print ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar ajax mas no seu exemplo fica mais fácil assim:

Seu formulário:

```
<form method="post" id="CODNOME" action="imprimir.php">
      <nav class="zz z_meio2 borda ">
  insira o codigo
<br>
      <input type="text" name="CODNOME" id="CODNOME"><br>
      <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>

      </nav>
    </form>
```

Arquivo imprimir.php:

```
<?

    if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "001"){
      $msg = "mensagem1";
    } 

    else if($_POST['CODNOME'] == "002"){
      $msg = "mensagem2";
    }

    else {
      $msg = "opção fixa";
    }


   ?>    
<div class="print" STYLE="width:660px;">
      <?php echo $msg;?>
         <p>*conteúdo html e php</p> 
    </div>
```

Comment: nao deu certo pois ja tentei preciso exatamente é fazer o tratamento desse código php em javascript.

Comment: @LuccasCerqueira a minha resposta é válida. Você pode utilizar ajax ou o código mencionado. Ele irá enviar diretamente para a página de impressão e colocar na div a variável $msg. Edite a sua resposta e explique  melhor o que você necessita caso a resposta não tenha servido (y).

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo exemplo utilizando 2 arquivos, um para o form e outro para imprimir.

index.php (Formulário)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function(){
                    $("#btn").click(function(){
                            var aluno = $("input[name=aluno]").val();
                            var data = $("input[name=data]").val();
                            var horario = $("input[name=horario]").val();
                            var valor = $("input[name=valor]").val();
                            $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: { primeiro:aluno, segundo:data, terceiro:horario, quarto:valor },
                                    url: "imprime.php",
                                    dataType: "html",
                                    success: function(result){
                                            $("#imprime").html('');
                                            $("#imprime").append(result);
                                    },
                                    beforeSend: function(){
                                            $('#loading').css({display:"block"});
                                    },
                                    complete: function(msg){
                                            $('#loading').css({display:"none"});
                                    }
                            });

                    });
            });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="loading" style="display: none;">Carregando...</div>
    <input type="text" name="aluno" /></br>
    <input type="text" name="data" /></br>
    <input type="text" name="horario" /></br>
    <input type="text" name="valor" /></br>
    <button id="btn">Imprimir</button>
    <div id="imprime"></div>
</body>
```

imprime.php

```
echo $_POST["primeiro"].'</br>'.
$_POST["segundo"].'</br>'.
$_POST["terceiro"].'</br>'.
$_POST["quarto"];
```